# Issue with showing 0-fractions in the timestamp in Python

Tags: python, timestamp, strptime

Python doesn't print the 0-fractions but I would like to have them printed:

```
print(datetime.datetime.strptime("2019-10-01T00:00:00.000", '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f'))
```

How it can be solved?

Comment: Problem is that you use here default formatting for printing; `strptime` is for _parsing_ datetime in given format. You want to use `strftime` to format the output string. Using the same format that you gave to `strptime` would result in zeroes being shown in output.

Comment: Side note: better use `datetime.datetime.fromisoformat("2019-10-01T00:00:00.000")` here for parsing string to datetime object.

Answer (score 1):

This could be a solution:

```
import datetime

print(datetime.datetime.strptime("2019-10-01T00:00:00.000", '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f').isoformat(timespec='microseconds').replace("T", " "))
```

The ouput will be:

```
2019-10-01 00:00:00.000000
```